# Detecting if a bit is set (at compile time)

Tags: c++, compile-time

How to detect if bit at position n is set in constant variable?

Comment: A variable doesn't exist at compile time, right?

Comment: In a *variable*? At *compile time*? Can you give an example?

Comment: You can't - a *variable* changes at *runtime*. Do you mean a *constant* perhaps?

Comment: @All sorry guys, meant constant.

Comment: @There: you're right, they're all wrong. In C++, when we do `const int n = 21;`, `n` is indeed called a *variable* even though it can't vary (3/4: "A variable is introduced by the declaration of an object"). The fact that C++ terminology doesn't match precisely with the English language is something C++ programmers need to get used to, because if they don't they will eventually misinterpret something or other in the standard, for example thinking that something said of "variables" doesn't apply to `n` because it's (in their opinion but not the standard's) "a constant not a variable".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
template<std::uint64_t N, std::uint8_t Bit>
struct is_bit_set
{
    static bool const value = !!(N & 1u << Bit);
};
```

`!!` is used to succinctly coerce the value into a `bool` and avoid data truncation compiler warnings.

Comment: this answer is nicest in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

```
int const a = 4;
int const bitset = !!((1 << 2) & a);
```

Now, `bitset` is `1`. It would be `0` if you for example stored a `3`. Yes, `a` is a *variable*.

Comment: Why not just `int bitset = ((1 << 2) & a) != 0);`?

Comment: @RedX yes `bitset` is a constant expression. You could use it for array dimensions like `int array[bitset + 1];`.

Comment: @Johannes thanks for your answer, would you mind explaining **why** this works?

Comment: @johannes Ok. Other question: Why do you need the double negation at the beginning?

Comment: @RedX : The first coerces into a `bool` (value of `0` or `1` only); the second gives the value actually desired.

Comment: @RedX because otherwise `bitset` contains `4` and not `1`. @There, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation, lookup "AND" and "bitshifts".

Comment: @Johannes +1, as this is good answer, but I will accept ildjarn's as his is "more C++" way.

Comment: @Johnsyweb only if you have imagination ;)

Comment: Also, my answer will yield undefined behavior if you shift it in a way that makes the number negative. It's a fair choice, since he obviously put more thought into his answer.

Comment: @Johannes I'm glad that you agree with me on that.

Answer (score 2):

The same thing as [user ildjarn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/636019/ildjarn) suggests in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676026/detecting-if-a-bit-is-set-at-compile-time/5676072#5676072), but with so-called ["enum trick"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5151683) that guarantees the compiler will do all the computation in compile time:

```
template<std::uint64_t N, std::uint8_t Bit>
struct is_bit_set
{
    enum { value = ( N & (1u << Bit) ) != 0 };
};
```

Comment: I don't *think* this is necessary on any C++03/C++11 compliant compiler, but I'm too tired to go digging through the standard at the moment. In any case, you should probably change it to `!!(N & (1u << Bit))` so the value will be strictly constrained to `0` or `1`.

Comment: @ildjarn: Thank you, I've edited it in an equivalent fashion.