# Enum and anonymous enum in C++

Tags: c++

**1)** The following code shows the index of the **enum element wednesday** .How can i make it to print the value instead of the index.

```
int main()
{
    enum day{sunday,monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday};
    day d=wednesday;
    cout<<d;
    return 0;
}
```

**2)** In what situation will I prefer **anonymous enum** over **enum**

Comment: This code prints the value of the enum.

Comment: I'm assuming he means to print "wednesday".

Comment: But what changes should I make like `cout<<day[d]`(it is wrong) to print iteral value instead.

Comment: Enums are not containers.

Comment: @SlxS : Yes I want to print **wednesday**

Comment: enums are just a fancy way to dress up numbers in your code. They are there to make your code more readable, but at the end of the day they are just integers.

Comment: @InsaneCoder Perhaps following the example from this? http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/2949/ as far as I'm aware, there's no automatic way to do it in C++. (It's the same method as pretty much any of the answers below. You have to maintain the name array)

Comment: Any help with the second part please?

Comment: @InsaneCoder I think this covers it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147008/the-usage-of-anonymous-enums

Answer (score 8):

1). Your code prints the value of the enum, not the index. In your specific example, the index is the same as the value (by default, the first value of an enum gets the numerical value 0, and the rest get consecutive increasing values.

To check:

```
int main()
{
    enum day{sunday = 5,monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday};
    day d=wednesday;
    cout<<d; // will print 8 (as in 5 + 1 + 1 + 1)
    return 0;
}
```

If by "print the value" you meant printing "wednesday", you should do this:

```
enum day{sunday,monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday};

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const day d)
{
    static const char *as_strings[] = {"sunday", "monday",
        "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday"
    };
    return out << as_strings[static_cast<int>(d)]; // this only works 
                 // for enum values starting from 0 and being consecutive
                 // otherwise you should use a switch(d) and 
                 // print each value separately
}

int main()
{
    day d=wednesday;
    cout<<d; // will print wednesday
    return 0;
}
```

Edit:

> 2) In what situation will I prefer anonymous enum over enum

You prefer an anonymous enum when you do not need to pass it as a parameter, but need to assign meaningful names to constant numeric values:

```
my_object record_to_myobject(record& r)
{
    enum {id, value1, value2}; // indexes within record
    int result_id = r[id]; // much more meaningful than r[0]
    int result_value1 = r[value1];
    int result_value2 = r[value2];
    return my_object{result_id, result_value1, result_value2};
}
```

It's fine to use an anonymous enum here because where you pass the value as argument, you need an int, not an enum type. If you need an enum type, then you have to give it a name. Otherwise, you do not.

Comment: So if I have to make a comparison then I should do it like `if(d==8)` instead of `if(d==wednesday)`?

Comment: With enums, you should never use their integer values explicitly. Basically, you should always use `if(d == wednesday)`. This will allow you to change the enum value, without going through code and changing it to match (`day d=wednesday; if(d == wednesday)` will allways evaluate to true, no matter the value of wednesday in the enum).

Comment: Thanks for your effort.It helped me a lot.Can You help with the cecond part.

Answer (score 3):

First, the language doesn't provide any means of mapping the
internal enum value to a string.  It can't, really; consider:

```
enum Numbers {
    one = 1,
    two = 2,
    three = 3,
    un = 1,
    deux = 2,
    trois = 3
};
```

Once you've assigned the enum constant to an enum variable, it
contains the numerical value, and nothing else.  And if the
numerical value in the above is 2, how can the system know
whether it should map to `two` or to `deux`.

In practice, the mapping *is* useful in many contexts.  A long
time ago, I wrote a simple parser to generate the mapping code;
it ignores most of C++, won't work in cases where e.g. the
enum is wrapped in a macro, the code it generates won't
compile if the enum is private or protected, and it's undefined
which string you get in cases like the above, but I've still
found it extremely useful.

For the second question: anonymous enums are usually used when
the only purpose of the enum is to generate constants.  Things
like:

```
enum { maxSize = 4096 };
```

were widely used before you could provide the initialization
constant for static member variables.  And I've often found it
convenient to define bit masks using an anonymous enum, even
when the actual values were on some sort of unsigned type.
Things like:

```
enum {
    offsetMask = 0xF000,
    offsetShift = 12,
    NS = 0x100,
    CWR = 0x80,
    ECE = 0x40,
    URG = 0x20,
    ACK = 0x10,
    //  ...
};
uint16_t flags;
//  ...
flags = offset << offsetShift | ACK;
```

I don't want to declare my variables to have an enum; they must
be exactly 16 bits (according to the TCP specification).  In C,
I'd probably have used a `#define`, and in modern C++, I might
use `static uint16_t const` member variables, but through out
most of my C++ career, something like the above would have been
the normal solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually maintain an array of string "descriptions" of the enum values, which is tedious and error-prone:

```
static const char *daydescs[] = {
    "sunday", "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday"
};

int main()
{
    enum day{sunday,monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday};
    day d=wednesday;
    cout<< daydescs[(unsigned)d];
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An enum is a number, the string representation (e.g. wednesday) is a compile time representation.

You would need something like:

```
const char *dayname[] = {"sunday","monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday","saturday"};

...
cout << dayname[(unsigned)d];
...
```

Comment: Just for the record, you don't need the cast.

Answer (score 0):

Try code below :

```
int main()
{
    enum day{sunday,monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday};
    String days[7] = {"sunday","monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday","saturday"};
    day d=wednesday;
    cout<<days[d];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks,I took enums as Arrays.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you only want the integer value, you can write an `operator <<` overload:

```
template<typename _stream>
_stream& operator << (const day& value) {
  _stream << static_cast<int>(value);
  return _stream;
}
```

Also, consider using **enum class** instead of a plain **enum** (if you are allowed to use C++11, of course).

2) I would say there could be 1 such case: namespace constants, say you have a `Person` class and want to have some in-class constants like `MaxAge` or `MaxNameLength`. But even in such cases, wrapping restrictions in something like `enum class Settings` is usually worth it.

Answer (score 0):

A type-safe variation on this theme would be to use `enum class` and use it as a key in `std::map`

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    enum class day
    {
        sunday,
        monday,
        tuesday,
        wednesday,
        thursday,
        friday,
        saturday
    };    

    std::map<day,std::string> days = 
    {
        std::make_pair(day::sunday, "Sunday"),
        std::make_pair(day::monday, "Monday"),
        std::make_pair(day::tuesday, "Tuesday"),
        std::make_pair(day::wednesday, "Wednesday"),
        std::make_pair(day::thursday, "Thursday"),
        std::make_pair(day::friday, "Friday"),
        std::make_pair(day::saturday, "Saturday")
    };
    std::cout << days[day::sunday] << std::endl;
}
```

This means that accessing the map with an integral type will cause a compile-time error.

Comment: On the other hand, you don't want to write this code by hand, and it's easy enough for your code generator to wrap it in a typesafe function.  Which can be made to work even in the constructors of static objects.