# Odd use of enum as a constant

Tags: c++, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a reason to use enum to define a single constant in C++ code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377695/is-there-a-reason-to-use-enum-to-define-a-single-constant-in-c-code)

I just came across the following snippet in some old code, with an odd use of enum:-

```
class MyClass
{
public:
  enum {MAX_ITEMS=16};
  int things[MAX_ITEMS];
...
} ;
```

This is better than `#define MAX_ITEMS 16` but is it any different from `static const int MAX_ITEMS=16;`?

Digging back into the mists of memory, I remember some C++ compilers not allowing you to initialize consts within the class, instead requiring a separate...

`const int MyClass::MAX_ITEMS = 16;`

... in the .cpp source file. Is this just an old workaround for that?

Comment: It's possible you remember not being able to initialize something that wasn't a `static const` integral type, which was the case before C++11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the age old ***"[enum hack](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_c++/Chapter08_023.html)"*** used to initialize arrays inside the class definition.

Traditionally, pre C++03 it was not possible to initialize a `static` `const` inside the class declaration. Since array declaration needs a compile time constant index in declaration. The ***enum hack*** was used as an workaround.

```
class A 
{
    enum { arrsize = 2 };
    static const int c[arrsize] = { 1, 2 };

};
```

Comment: http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_c++/Chapter08_023.html

Comment: @Roddy: Exactly. I don't see why the Q is closed as a duplicate because it is not.It does not ask which one is better, enum or const it asks, a specific Q.