# Why does this C++ code use an anonymous enum rather than a const variable?

Tags: c++, enums, webrtc

I've been reading some of the WebRTC source code and saw this interesting construction to define a constant:

```
namespace webrtc {
  enum { kNameOfConstant = 200 };
  // ...
}
```

Personally, I would have written `const int kNameOfConstant = 200;`. What's the advantage of writing constants in this way, using an anonymous enum with a single member? Thanks!

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377695/is-there-a-reason-to-use-enum-to-define-a-single-constant-in-c-code

Comment: In older versions of C++, constant integers could not be used in array declarations, but enumeration values could.

Comment: Because that's the way the author write it. Ask him or her.